# Object reference in callback method

Tags: java

In the below code when processStateChange() method is called, how does the compiler knows which object to pass?

```
public void onUpdate(Set<Object> objects)
{
    for(Object object : objects)
    {
        object.addUpdateListener(new UpdateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate()
            {
                processStateChange(object);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any difference in response if the loop is: for(final Object object : object)?

Comment: Object `object` is not changed in loop, so it is effectively final, so you can omit `final` keyword

Comment: The variable must be final or *effectiveley final*, which it is in your loop since you don't change the value of the variable in it's scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to understand what is going on, here is how java compiler sees your code:

```
public void onUpdate(Set<Object> objects) {
    for(Object object : objects) {
        object.addUpdateListener(new MyUpdateListener(object));
    }
}

class MyUpdateListener implements UpdateListener {
    final Object myObj; // I'm intentionally using different name here
    MyUpdateListener(Object myObj) {
        this.myObj = myObj;
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdate() {
        processStateChange(this.myObj);
    }
}
```

so, multiple instances of UpdateListener  are created, each holds reference to it's own `object`

Comment: Thanks @llya this is exactly what I'm looking for.